# How can i open a file using a python script i coded?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, file-handling

I would like to open a file such as an image file using a python script, and by doing so, pass the file name and location into the script when i choose to open the image in my script.

*clicks "open image in another program" in windows 10*

```py
import tkinter as tk

filename = fileopen.name()
filelocation = fileopen.path()


window = tk.Tk()
imagepic = tk.PhotoImage(file=filelocation)
picture = tk.Label(window, image=imagepic)
window.mainloop()
```

I'm pretty sure theres a module that allows for this but i just cannot find it.

Comment: Is there a dialog that lets the user select the image?

Comment: i could do that but i want to make the program more seamless

Comment: _clicks "open image in another program"_ is this a context menu(using right click)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant originally was how to go about registering a context menu option in windows explorer allowing the user to right click a file and select "Open with " - passing the file into the script as an argument.

In order to achieve this, you can follow this [guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/add-opening-methods-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files-in-win/), supplying this command:

```
python -m <absolute/path/to/yourscript> %1
```

The %1 will be the file as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question correctly, but for dealing with the operating system you would use the module `os`:

```
import os
os.startfile(filelocation)  # Open file in win10 default program
```